# Specify custom entry point path

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a gcp function with custom entry point path. File at location `src/custom.js` relative to `package.json` contains delcarations that I'd like gcp to invoke:

```
functions.http('helloHttp', async (req, res) => {
    //code
});
```

I tried specifying entry-point with:

```
 gcloud functions deploy function-1 --entry-point=src/custom.js/helloHttp --runtime nodejs20 --trigger-http --project projectId
```

and

```
gcloud functions deploy function-1 --entry-point=helloHttp --runtime nodejs20 --trigger-http --project projectId
```

But I get an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Could not create or update Cloud Run service function-1, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'function-1-00012-doj' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Whats the correct way to specify custom entry point when running google cloud functions?

Comment: "*Logs for this revision might contain more information.*". So, what do the logs say? Please edit the question to add full details.

Comment: Logs just repeat the console output. It may be that I am looking into the wrong tab.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. package.json needs a `main` field set to the location of file that contains entry point, in my case `httpHello`. In my case:

```
"main": "./src/custom.js"
```

does the job.